# Exporting long numbers to CSV file for Excel

Tags: sql, excel, csv, long-integer

This is perhaps one of those many times discussed questions with solutions more specific to actual system that outputs the data into a CSV file.

Is there a simple way to export data like 3332401187555, 9992401187000 into a CSV file in a way that later when opened in Excel, the columns won't show them in "scientific" format? Should this be important, the data is retrieved directly by an SQL SELECT statement from any DBMS.

This also means that I've tried solutions like surrounding the values with apostrophes '3332401187555' and the Excel cell recognizes those as text and doesn't do any conversions/masking. Was wondering if there was a more elegant way without actually it being a pre-set Excel template with text data fields.

Comment: I hope this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13732077/how-to-import-long-number-from-csv-to-excel-without-converting-to-scientific-not

Answer (score 1):

```
1. Try exporting the numbers prefixed with single quote. Example: '3332401187555.
2. In excel, select the column containing number values 
and then select Number in Format Cells.
```

Comment: Thank you, will try the single quote. The column formatting also works well, just need to cut off two digits after the point, however, need to have the file readily working as it's consumed by others )

Comment: In case of any issue please do comment, will help you out.

Answer (score -1):

Just have to save your file with Excel the option CSV file. And you have the in file in requested format.